# Ignore folder only if it is not inside other folder

Tags: git

I would to ignore `bin` folder (in .gitignore) only if it is not part of `packages` folder. Is it possible/?

**Update.**

I would to exclude the following situations:

```
packages/bin
packages/somefolder/bin
etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create negated entries in your `.gitignore`:

```
bin/
!packages/bin/
!packages/*/bin/
!packages/*/*/bin/
```

Unfortunately git does not support the `**` glob for multiple directory levels (or regexp matches), so to ignore `packages/whatever/bin` and `packages/whatever/whatever/bin` you need two entries (and so on for deeper nesting).

Demo:

```
[adrian@hades:/tmp/gitignore:master]> git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       foo/bar/bin/
#       foo/baz/bin/
#       packages/bin/
#       packages/xxx/bin/
#       packages/xxx/yyy/bin/
#       xxx/packages/bin/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

[adrian@hades:/tmp/gitignore:master]> cat > .gitignore
bin/
!packages/bin/
!packages/*/bin/
!packages/*/*/bin/

[adrian@hades:/tmp/gitignore:master]> git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .gitignore
#       packages/bin/
#       packages/xxx/bin/
#       packages/xxx/yyy/bin/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Please look at update. I also want exclude something like: packages/somefolder/bin